# Why do my variables suddenly become none?

Tags: python

This is My code, why does my variable, individual_cost, print correctly using the print statement but becomes non on the return?

```
def determine_individual_menu_item(total_food_cost):

    individual_cost = total_food_cost

    food_item = input("Enter food item: ")

    if food_item == "1" or food_item == "2" or food_item == "3" or food_item == "4" or food_item == "5" or food_item == "6" or food_item == "7":

        food_item = int(food_item)
        food_cost = get_cost_of_food_items(food_item)

    else:
        print("Please enter a food item on the menu.")
        determine_individual_menu_item(total_food_cost)

    yes_or_no = input("Is that the end of the order (y/n)? ")
    if yes_or_no =="y":
        individual_cost = acumulate_food_cost(individual_cost , food_cost)
        print(str(individual_cost))
        return individual_cost
    if yes_or_no =="n":
        individual_cost = acumulate_food_cost(individual_cost , food_cost)
        determine_individual_menu_item(individual_cost)
```

Answer (score 0):

If a Python function reaches the end of its scope, it implicitly returns `None`. As such, unless `yes_or_no_=="y"`, your function will return `None`. You can fix this by adding a `return individual_cost` to an `else` clause and the end of the `if yes_or_no=="n"` block

Comment: Clearly this code is missing a return statement in cases other than `yes_or_no == "y"`, but the question _claims_ that the print statement is being executed correctly, which would imply that `y` has been entered, so it should then reach the existing `return` statement. If this is accurate, then I suspect that they are trying to inspect a variable called `individual_cost` outside of the function scope, without having assigned the return value to a variable in the caller. It would be worth asking the OP to share the calling code.

Comment: OP is probably testing with multiple items each time. The first function call will then take the `n` path, and the only thing that will print and return is the final recursive call where `y` is entered. Since that's not being propagated to the first call though, the first call returns `None`